# how to get this matrix?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Do carmo's book and I don't understand one thing in chapter 3 about geodecics. If we define F: U$\to$M$\times$M by $F(q,v)=(q,exp_qv)$, consider the point $F(p,0)=(p,p)$, why the matrix of $dF_{(p,0)}$ is 
\begin{equation*}
M=\begin{bmatrix}
I & I\\
0 & I\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
I don't quite know how to get $\frac{dexp_pv}{dv}$. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DoCarmo does exactly this calculation in Proposition 2.9 on p. 65.